# How to extend the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

When I try to add a view immediately under the ActionBar, it only seems to work if I add an ImageView, as shown below.

The same doesn't work with LinearLayout, or RelativeLayout, and instead removes all of the ActionBar's initial content and replaces it with the Linear/ Relative Layout content.

Why can't I successfully add LinearLayout, or RelativeLayout, or what might I be getting wrong. I just started working with Android.

I'm aiming for something like this:
[image]

-- THE CODE

Extend our ActionBar by adding an ImageView

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.center16);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM
            | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);
```

Using a Linear or Relative layout

```
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View linearorrelative = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbarextend, null);

    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM
            | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
    linearorrelative.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    actionBar.setCustomView(linearorrelative);
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an [ActionView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView)

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting a search bar below the `ActionBar`, you should consider using the new [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html). Which is:

> a generalization of action bars for use within application layouts

Here's an example implementation using the new [AppCompat library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), based on your image:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Your content here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

}
```

---

```
<style name="Your.Base.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

---

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"...>

    <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Your.Base.Theme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Results**

[image: results]

Otherwise, as suggested by @ChrisStillwell, consider using an [`ActionView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) and placing the `SearchView` in the `ActionBar` as a `MenuItem`.